# Miniature Overview in Vim

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, notepad++

SmartHighlighter for notepad++ can mark all occurences of a searched term in the scroll bar. In [SublimeText 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) you can see a miniature of the hole file. Is there anything similar for (g)vim?

I tried a mapping to toggle the fontsize between normal and smallest possible, but it's not optimum.

Comment: I think the best approach in (g)vim depends on what you're trying to do. For instance, if you're coding, there's a terrific plugin called [tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) that lets you browse the structure of source codes really efficiently. Also, try `:g/regex/p`, which will print all lines that match `regex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean minimap on sublime text2? Then use minimap-vim

https://github.com/koron/minimap-vim

Comment: Ooooh, nice hack. It doesn't help with the OP's search needs, though.

Comment: This is a bit dirty. I can't turn it on and off and on again. Since my gvim runs fullscreen I allways have to mark the window to stay on top. But generally that is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only have a single global font size, whether you use GVim or Vim in a terminal emulator.

Doing anything outside of the default cell-based view is AFAIK impossible: you'll most probably never get those marks in the scrollbar (searching in Chrome does the same thing if I inderstood your description).

If you are searching for something that is not a function or a variable, etc. in a large buffer, your best bet is to use Vim's quickfix:

```
:vim[grep] foo % | cw
```

If you are searching for function, variable, etc., you should try [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) (both depend on [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)).